# how to show comma separated values using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter geting  comma separated values but not working fine. i am sharing all code like first output foreach  after gating result not show comma separated values than second show array print value aftra need output comma separated values like **SLR,ACCN**

**Model code here**

```
public function display_coach_name($coachID='')
            {   
        $db2 = $this->load->database('rail',TRUE);
        $ids = explode(',',$coachID);
        $db2->select('coach_name');
        $db2->from('mcc_coach');
        $db2->where_in('id',$ids);
        $query = $db2->get();
        //echo $db2->last_query(); die;

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0):

        return $query->result_array();
        else:
            return 0;
        endif;
            }
```

**output**

```
<?php foreach ($coachname as $val){ echo $pizza = $val['coach_name']; }?>
```

//---------------------foreach-----------------output---

```
SLRACCN
```

**array print**

```
$coachname = $this->rail_ceil_model->display_coach_name($coachID);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($coachname);
//---------------------output----------------------
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => GS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => SLR
            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => GS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => SLR
            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => GS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => SLR
            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => GS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [coach_name] => SLR
            )

    )
```

**I have need output**

SLR,ACCN

Comment: Do you want comma separated values from array?

Comment: yes sir i am sharing all issue and output result

Comment: i have need output result like (SLR,ACCN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implode function for converting array into comma separated values

```
$coachname = $this->rail_ceil_model->display_coach_name($coachID);
foreach($coachname as $val){
if(is_array($val)){
   $list .= $val['coach_name'].',';        
}}

print_r(substr ( $list , 0 , strlen($list) -1 ));
```

or

```
$coachname = $this->rail_ceil_model->display_coach_name($coachID);
print_r(implode(', ', array_map('coach_name', $coachname)));
```

or

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($coachname, 'coach_name'));
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/assign_train.php

Line Number: 72

Answer (score 0):

You may use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function for getting comma separated values.

```
<?php
$coachname = array("ACCN", "SLR", "CN");
$new = implode(',',$coachname);
echo $new;
?>
```

Output will be:

`ACCN,SLR,CN`

Edit your code accordingly.

Comment: $coachname = array("ACCN", "SLR", "CN"); ?

Comment: i have geting value just array show on form how can geting value like $coachname = array("ACCN", "SLR", "CN");?

Answer (score 0):

Please use array_map function then use implode function

```
$coachname_separated = array_map (function($value){
    return $value['coach_name'];
} , $coachname);

$List = implode(', ', $coachname_separated); 

echo $List;
```